# How can we initialize the activerecord object with jsonb attributes based on the json structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I have a `user` model with `address` field as `jsonb` column. I am using the gem [activerecord_json_validator](https://github.com/mirego/activerecord_json_validator)
 for validating jsonb schema.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
#name :string, age :integer, address :jsonb

  include SchemaStructures
  validates :address, allow_blank: true, json: { message: lambda { |errors|
    errors
  }, schema: JSON_SCHEMA_ADDRESS }


end
```

Now if I initialize the object it will show the jsonb attribute as `nil`

```
User.new()
{name: nil, age: nil, address: nil}
```

But is it possible to generate the `address` structure from existing `json_schema`. so it will show like a normal object but nested like below

```
{name: nil, age: nil, address: {'city': nil, postcode: nil}}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can also use `attribute` method to set the default values: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to do this in the model. But you can set defaults for the `address` jsonb field on the database level. For this try to create a migration:

```
change_column_default :users, :address, { 'city': nil, postcode: nil }
```

Comment: I think it's better to do it in after_initialize without any DB updation. But Still,  couldn't find a way to generate the fields from the existing json schema